# Data Passed to Controller Not Being Saved in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a "Create" ActionResult that is being passed data back from the view, but the data is not being saved to the database.  I know that the data is getting passed to the controller correctly, because I have followed it all through the process with the debugger, however when the POST action is completed, the data is not saved.  The "Project" is created, but the Users (public virtual, so it is actually stored in a table called ApplicationUserProjects) field is not saved.  The field is populated while the code is running, but once the action is complete, the data is not added to that table, and as far as I can tell, is completely gone.  This is the code from the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Project Manager, SuperUser")]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Project project, List<string> Developers, List<string> ProjectManagers)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            var projectsHelper = new ProjectsHelper();
            foreach (var user in Developers)
            {
                projectsHelper.AssignUserToProject(user, project);
                //project.Users.Add(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user));
                //db.SaveChanges();
            }
            foreach (var user in ProjectManagers)
            {
                projectsHelper.AssignUserToProject(user, project);
                //project.Users.Add(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user));
                //db.SaveChanges();
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(project);
    }
```

The commented out code in the foreach loops represent different efforts I have made to solve this problem, with no success.

And this is the helper method being used by the controller:

```
public bool AssignUserToProject(string userId, Project project)
        {
            if (!IsUserAssignedToProject(userId, project))
            {
                project.Users.Add(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId));
                //project.Users.Add(user);

            }

            if (IsUserAssignedToProject(userId, project))
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I don't know if it will matter, but here is section of the View dealing with these input fields:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Project</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:300px;" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
        @Html.Label("Developers", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBox("Developers", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:300px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Users, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Users, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
        @Html.Label("Project Managers", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ListBox("ProjectManagers", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", style = "max-width:300px;" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Users, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
If I move the db.SaveChanges(); line anywhere below the foreach blocks, when that line is reached, I get this error: "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code  {"The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects."}"

Comment: Perform all the operations and then add `db.SaveChanges()` at last before redirection can resolve your issue. Remove `db.SaveChanges()` from all other places.

Comment: You shouldn't need to call SaveChanges() multiple times. Compose your object graph and save it all at once as shown [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-one-to-many-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx). For the existing children, you may need to set their [entity state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx) or you can update via foreign key instead of the nav property.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the condition in your code is wrong. It has to be like this:

```
public bool AssignUserToProject(string userId, Project project)
{
    if (!IsUserAssignedToProject(userId, project))
    {
        project.Users.Add(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId));
        db.SaveChanges();
        return false;
    }

    return true;            
}
```

After Add a entity you have to call SaveChanges to really save the data in database.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change any behavior.  The data is still not being saved.

Comment: Are you sharing the instance of your context? Or each class has its own context?

Comment: Each class has its own context.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AssignUserToProject` function change the line

```
project.Users.Add(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId));
```

to

```
project.Users.Add(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(userId)));
```

to compare strings in the database.

This assumes the u.Id field is also a string.  Otherwise, you'll need to parse the field to the appropriate data type before the equals comparison.

**EDIT**

Also check any equality operations in `IsUserAssignedToProject` to make sure it correctly compares user IDs in any LINQ queries inside that function.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change any behavior.  The data is still not being saved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had something to do with having a different context in the controller class and in the helper class, in addition to "db.Projects.Add(project)" being in the wrong place to save all of the data.  Here is a cleaned-up version of the code in the controller that actually works.  Using the helper method was not needed, so things are much tidier now.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Project Manager, SuperUser")]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name")] Project project, List<string> Developers, List<string> ProjectManagers)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var user in Developers)
        {
            project.Users.Add(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user));
        }
        foreach (var user in ProjectManagers)
        {
            project.Users.Add(db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user));
        }
    }
    db.Projects.Add(project);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

Comment: You may prefer to use the helper for every db related action, so they are all at the same place (tidier) and it is easier to **test** all of them.